# Mount an ISO Image on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iso

We have a Windows 2003 server that we access via remote desktop.

We do not have access to the internet from that server. We would therefore like to mount an ISO file to install a service pack.

What is the best way to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just mount the ISO with [VCD control panel](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe) or [Daemon tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads), or something similar, then run the service pack installer from the mounted ISO.

Comment: Daemon tools, last time I checked, tries to install some sort of adware (a toolbar?).  They do however, give you the option not to install it during the install, so just watch for that.

Comment: VCD control panel on the other hand is quite a fine program, accepting that it's not going to be as fully functional as some of the competition.  Lightweight, gets the job done, and doesn't get in your way.

Answer (score 4):

[MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) is free and very lightweight.

Comment: The magic suite is a very lightweight, very powerful set of tools.

Comment: Does it require a reboot after installation? Any malware installed with MagicDisc?

Comment: @pic: No malware included, no. Not sure about the reboot though. I think that depends on which version of windows you are using. You will have to test it out. It might already work without rebooting even if the setup program tells you to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/) or have a look at [THIS](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/620/xp_small_free_way_to_use_and_mount_images_iso_files_without_burning_them/) link.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best free ISO mounting tool out there is [Pismo file mount](http://www.pismotechnic.com/pfm/).

Some highlights:

- Works great on Windows Vista/7 x64 (not natively x64 but completely compatible)
- Drives only exist when an ISO is mounted and are removed when there is no ISO mounted
- Small memory footprint
- Has simple minimalist right click shell integration
- Unattended installation
- No Branding or silly logos to speak of (very clean professional feeling program)
- Fully featured command line control that is automatically working right after unattended install
- Plus all the normal features you would expect from an ISO mounting tool
- Free for corporate use

Some things you will want to pay attention to though is that by default it will not mount the ISO to a drive letter but instead mount it to a UNC path which can cause some software installers to fail when installing from the mounted path. Just make sure you specify that you want Pismo to mount to a drive letter when you are doing the mount and it will work fine.

Here is the unattended install of SQL to demonstrate my real world use of Pismo.

```
SET MSDNIsoPath=\\itapp\ISO Library\MSDN
SET ScriptPath=%~dp0
SET ScriptPath=%ScriptPath:~0,-1%
SET MountPath=m:
SET pfmMount=pfm mount -m %MountPath%
SET pfmUnMount=pfm unmount

echo -Installing Pismo File Mount
"%ResourcePath%\pfmap-051.exe" /q

echo.
echo Install and configure Microsoft SQL Server 2005 
echo -Installing Standard Edition
%pfmMount% "%MSDNIsoPath%\en_sql_2005_std_x86_dvd.iso"
%MountPath%\Servers\setup.exe /settings "%ScriptPath%\Configuration\Microsoft SQL Server 2005.ini" /qb /norestart
%pfmUnMount%
```

Comment: Does Pismo require a reboot after installation? I would be using it on a production box, so, can not reboot.

Comment: No pismo does not. Simply start using pfm from the command line directly after the unattended install and your good to go, no reboot required.