# Mount an ISO Image on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I followed the instructions on [mount-an-iso-image-on-windows-2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/87305/mount-an-iso-image-on-windows-2003). I don't see the the drive after mounting.

I used the Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel v2.0.1.1 from microsoft.
[Virtual CD-ROM](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe)

**Anyone have a simple clean way of mounting ISO image on Win 2008 Server?**

I would be mounting on a production box, so, can not reboot. I wanted something simple and easy to use and free. It is for a one time use to install software that was packaged in an ISO image.

Comment: I wonder if this requires a reboot? http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install .iso file on a remote server without DVD drive access](http://serverfault.com/questions/110332/install-iso-file-on-a-remote-server-without-dvd-drive-access)

Comment: don't forget to run as admin. That will hose you as well.

Comment: I was able to install magiciso on Windows Server 2008 R2 without requiring a reboot.

Comment: See also [Freeware ISO mount software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7211/2210) on the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Comment: I use win2k8 in a virtualized environment, and I solve this task from the hypervisor (i.e. attach iso image as virtual cd drive). It is a more clear way to do that. In your case it probably not feasible, but for the googlers of the future it may be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not mount it?

I mean, seriously. You can't reboot? Ok. This is for software on a server that came with an ISO image? Ok.

So what?

- Mount ISO image on your workstation
- Copy files to server.
- Install.

I do that all the time. Server software (usually) comes without disc based copy protection.

Comment: Good point for not mounting. + 1 But copying uncompressed file over wire, which could be well into the gigabytes, that would take a while.

Comment: Not if you do compress them again, like with 7zip.

Comment: Can't reboot the server, careful on the server because it's production use, and you are hesitant to copy the data over because it's large? Not asking much, are you? :-p

Burn the iso from a workstation? Or extract using "daemon tools" virtual CD-ROM software from a workstation, copy the files to a USB thumbdrive, plug that into the server and Bob's your uncle. Should be good to go.

Answer (score 12):

I never mount ISOs on a server. I usually download 7-zip portable and extract them. No extra software installed on the server. No unneeded/unsupported drivers installed either.

Comment: This. this this this this this

Comment: But why shouldn't you mount an ISO on a server? It's essentially just an archive like a ZIP file. I don't see how this is any more dangerous than physically inserting the CD itself?

Comment: The problem isn't mounting the ISO, the problem is installing extra software and extra drivers on a server to facilitate the mounting. If you want to keep servers as clean and stable as possible, you don't install extra drivers unless you really need them. Standalone EXEs and portable software don't need an install, and don't install drivers.

Answer (score 5):

FYI - just installed the latest version of SlySoft's Virtual Clone drive on Win 2008 R2. Fully working without a reboot in just a few seconds! I've been using VCD for years without any issues and greatly prefer it over magiciso or daemontools (which I do have installed and in use on a few servers). - Jeremy

Answer (score 3):

I typically use winrar to extract the files to a directory on the server. Winrar setup does not require a reboot

Answer (score 2):

i think magic iso will allow you to mount an iso as a virtual disk, http://www.magiciso.com/

otherwise, i know for sure, daemon tools lite will allow you to mount an iso as a virtual disk, http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home though it is a bit more sketchy.

you will need to reboot after installing and setting up daemon tools, perhaps magic iso, as well.

there are virtual disk drivers that daemon tools loads after you reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html from SlySsoft. Works on x32 & x64. Also is freeware with no malware, tracking or adverts. Works with Windows 98 & higher

Edit: Neglected to read your can't reboot note. I believe this uses a kernel mode driver so a reboot would be required. You can use WinRar to extract the ISO image to a folder and install from that folder if so required.

Edit: Just tested on Server 2008 R2 and no reboot was necessary.

Comment: Slysoft clone drive is no longer available. Page says the site was taken down due to regulatory issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Magicdisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm?=mdisc_hlp106) (from magiciso) does not need a reboot after installation. Just did this myself today. I then mounted the iso (which was on my workstation) over the network, so no file copy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Wayne said, someone may also be interested to know that SlySoft's Virtual CloneDrive product also works on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core installation. I just used it to install the SP1 patch.